# Many to many relation and query builder

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I would like to extend my user repository. I will find all users with a specified role or
that satisfy an additional condition.

I try some queries with the query builder, but without success.

Here is an example of my database structure.

Tablename: **User**

```
+----+----------+-----------+
| id | isActive | isDeleted |
+----+----------+-----------+
|  1 |        1 |         0 |
+----+----------+-----------+
```

Tablename: **Role**

```
+----+-------+
| id | name  |
+----+-------+
|  1 | Admin |
+----+-------+
```

Tablename: **user_role**

ManyToMany relation between user and role

```
+---------+---------+
| user_id | role_id |
+---------+---------+
|       1 |       1 |
+---------+---------+
```

Tablename: **distance**

OneToMany relation between user and table distance

```
+----+---------+-----+------+
| id | user_id | lat | long |
+----+---------+-----+------+
|  1 |       1 |     |      |
+----+---------+-----+------+
```

I write a plain sql query, which is correct for me, but i do not know how can i realize
the many to many relation with the query builder.

```
SELECT u.id 
FROM user as u,  user_role  as ur 
WHERE u.id=ur.user_id and ur.role_id=1 OR 
(u.id not in (select user_id from distance) and ur.role_id=1 and u.id=ur.user_id);
```

Can someone give me a hint how I can solve this issue?

**Update**

I will show only some parts of the entities, because of readability and clarity.

```
class User implements AdvancedUserInterface, \Serializable
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     * @Exclude
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="App\UserBundle\Entity\Role", inversedBy="users")
     *
     */
    protected $roles;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\UserBundle\Entity\Distance", mappedBy="user", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
     * @Exclude
     */
    protected $distance;

}


class Role implements RoleInterface
{

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255)
     * @Exclude
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="App\UserBundle\Entity\User", mappedBy="roles")
     */
    private $users;
}


class Distance
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="distance", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $user;

}
```

Comment: Can you post your Entities?

Comment: I add some important parts of my entities, is this ok?

Comment: Mab82x, you can 'ping' users in comments by adding the "@" symbol in front of their name.  For example, you could say - @LordZed, I added some important parts of my entities.  Is this sufficient? - and the poster will be notified.

Comment: @AHiggins many thanks for this hint, i do not know this before :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try such DQL (or simillar). Please check [Doctrine DQL documenation](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#dql-select-examples)

```
SELECT u FROM App\UserBundle\Entity\User u
INNER JOIN u.role r
LEFT JOIN u.distance d
WHERE r.id = 1 OR (r.id = 1 AND d IS NULL)
```

BTW Are you sure that your SQL is ok? I am not sure if this is not give same results as

```
SELECT u.id 
FROM user as u,  user_role  as ur 
WHERE u.id=ur.user_id and ur.role_id=1
```

then DQL will be trivial

```
SELECT u FROM App\UserBundle\Entity\User u
INNER JOIN u.role r
WHERE r.id = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

@l3l0 a lot of thanks, this solve my issue :)

I add now following function in my user repository and everythins is ok :)

```
public function getUsers2Crawl($role)
{
    $query = $this->getEntityManager()->createQuery('SELECT u FROM App\UserBundle\Entity\User u INNER JOIN u.roles r LEFT JOIN u.distance d WHERE r.id = $role->getId() OR (r.id = $role->getId() AND d IS NULL)');
    return $query->getResult();
}
```